# SML compiler source code?

Tags: compiler-construction, sml

I know that this question may not belong here, but I'm going through the dragon book at the moment, to learn about writing compilers, and i wondered if anyone knows if it is possible to get the source code for the compiler for SML? I want to use it because it is a functional paradigm and if we forget about the small buffer it is a good compiler when it comes to optimize Functional code.

I also like to look at it, because it was the very first language i learned to program in.

Comment: http://www.smlnj.org/svn.html (google found me that in 30 seconds.)

Comment: I don't know whether to downvote your question since it isn't very well researched and is somewhat off-topic or upvote it since it is so commendable to want to look under the hood at how a major language implementation actually works. I'll split the difference and do neither. The dragon book is fairly old and concentrates on imperative languages. There is a huge gap in theory between that book and what an SML compiler does. Perhaps the book "Modern Compiler Implementation in ML" by Appel might be a good supplement to your reading.

Comment: I would also recommend http://plzoo.andrej.com/ which has a "miniml", along with the various other miniml implementations, while not a full language implementation or production compiler, it may help in understanding the overarching structure of an ml compiler

Answer (score 3):

As @rici mentioned in the comment section, you can find the smlnj source code [here](http://www.smlnj.org/svn.html).  Additionally,

- MLton source [here](https://github.com/MLton/mlton).
- HaMLet source [here](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/hamlet/)
- Moscow ML source [here](https://github.com/kfl/mosml)
- PolyML source [here](https://github.com/polyml/polyml)